# split multiple samecharacters onto their own line

Tags: regex, sed

I tried this

```
sed -r "s/]]/]\n]/g" testfile.txt
```

but I don't think it worked.

What i'm trying to do:

take

```
[[[sometext
```

would be

```
[
[
[sometext
```

or

```
[[[[[[[[sometext
```

would be

```
[
[
[
[
[
[
[
[sometext
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep -o` it is much easier than using `sed`:

```
s='[[[[[[[[sometext'

grep -o '\[[^[]*' <<< "$s"
[
[
[
[
[
[
[
[sometext
```

If you have to use `sed` then use:

```
sed 's/\[[^[]*/&\n/g' <<< "$s"
[
[
[
[
[
[
[
[sometext
```

Comment: I'm on windows btw.  I was hoping not to switch solutions.  This is for a 3rd party tool that will be using a lot of various tools and we were hoping to standardize around sed and command line.  The sample issue is SOME data within a larger dataset.  So it would be processed by line.  I was going to include the sed regex as a command; within a larger -e set of commands, or as a pre-parse stand-alone sed command... oh wait: this is it huh? \[[^[]*... this might work.  I can put gnuwin32 grep on I guess.

Comment: that adds a newline inbetween each [[.  I modified it: sed -e "s/\[[^[]*/&\r/g" sometext.txt.  Thank you!

Comment: the above solution works... but it has the unintended consequence of breaking a format I need...

Comment: Please clarify `unintended consequence of breaking a format`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` version:

```
echo "[[[[[[[[sometext"  | awk -v RS="[" 'NR>1{$1=$1;print RS$0}'
[
[
[
[
[
[
[
[sometext
```

Answer (score 0):

Input:

```
[[[[[sometext
```

Pattern

```
/(\[)(?=\[.*?)/g
```

Replacement

```
\1\r\n
```

Output:

```
[
[
[
[
[sometext
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nC3lK3/3)

Usage with `sed`

```
sed -r 's/(\[)(?=\[.*?)/\1\r\n/g' file.txt
```

Comment: um... did you see both my set of inputs?  It still results in [[ in my final output.